# VisualForce DataList Without Child Relationship

Tags: soql, custom

I have a `Place__c` record called "Massachusetts" with a `State_Code__c` field (e.g. "MA"). I'm trying to embed a `Visualforce Page`  on the `Place__c` Page Layout to show all `Account` records that have a `BillingState` that matches the `State_Code__c` field value of the current record (in this case, "MA"), and have it preferably look like a `Related List` in LEX.

**There is no relationship between place and account.** We just want to be able to look at all accounts that have a match to the State Code.

---

**VF Page AccountsinPlaces**

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Viewing Accounts">
         <apex:form id="theForm">
             <apex:pageBlockSection >
                 <apex:dataList value="{!AccountsinPlacesExt}" var="acct" type="1">
                     <a href="/one/one.app#/sObject/{!acct.id}/view">{!acct.name}</a>
                 </apex:dataList>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}">Previous</apex:commandlink>
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!next}">Next</apex:commandlink>
             </apex:panelGrid>
         </apex:form> 
     </apex:pageBlock> 

//..........
```

---

**Apex Class AccountsinPlacesExt**

```
 public with sharing class AccountsinPlacesExt {

public Place__c place;
  ApexPages.StandardController stdController;


    public AccountsinPlacesExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

stdController = Controller;
        place = (Place__c)stdController.getRecord();

    }

 public Account getAccount() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
                WHERE BillingState = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('State_Code__c')];
    }

}

//.............
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Does your code even compile? Actually... I assume, you don't know how to code in Apex. I suggest you start with https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro.htm

Comment: Soxdave this amount of communication on the answer clearly indicates that your question is not detailed enough. Please update your question. Explain what you are trying to do and in which context you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you're missing seems to just be that you need a `List<Account>` as your return type, not `Account`. You should write your [extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) as follows:

```
public with sharing class MyPlaceExtension
{
    public Place__c place { get; private set; }
    public List<Account> inStateAccounts { get; private set; }
    public MyPlaceExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // add the Place__c field that tells you which state
        List<String> neededFields = new List<String> { 'State_Code__c' };
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(neededFields);
        place = (Place__c)controller.getRecord();

        accounts = [
            SELECT Name FROM Account
            WHERE BillingState = :place.State_Code__c
        ];
    }
}
```

You can now use the `inStateAccounts` property in your `dataList`. You need the `page` tag to include the following properties (in addition to any others you want):

```
<apex:page standardController="Place__c" extensions="MyPlaceExtension">
```

Then your `dataList` tag should look like:

```
<apex:dataList value="{!inStateAccounts}" var="account">
```

Comment: how do you traverse the inStateAccounts list?

Comment: @soxdave Traverse? You just pass it into your `value` property on your `dataList`.

Comment: here's what i am trying: <apex:page standardController="Place__c" extensions="AccountsinPlacesExt">
 <apex:dataList value="{!inStateAccounts}" var="inStateAccounts" type="1">
        <a href="/one/one.app#/sObject/{!Account.id}/view">{!Account.name}</a>
    </apex:dataList>
</apex:page>

Comment: i get an error Error Error: Unknown property 'Place__cStandardController.Account'

Comment: @soxdave Your `var` should be `account`.

Comment: where can i figure this stuff out? i'm getting so lost ;)

Comment: also how can i style it so it looks like a related list in Lightning Experience (LEX)

Comment: That is a separate question entirely. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataList.htm) is usually a good place to start. If you look at the `var` property, the explanation is pretty thorough.

Comment: Sebastian, thanks for all of your initial help with the soql. Adrian - thanks so much. this helped perfectly.

Comment: how do you leave reps?

Comment: @soxdave What does that mean?

Comment: basically how do i give you points for helping me out? (also, how do i earn points so i'm not in the negative?)

Comment: Up vote and accept are the ways you can do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare two fields together in SoQL.  One way to do it is the following:

1. Create a checkbox formula field in the Account object that
   evaluates those two fields (call it "BillingStateMatch", for example)
2. Your soql should evaluate "BillingStateMatch = true"

That will give you your desired records.

**UPDATE - AFTER OP CLARIFICATION**

Try this instead

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController accountRecords {

  string placeId = '';
  Place__c thePlace = [select State_Code__c from Place__c where Id = :placeId];

  get {
    if(accountRecords == null) {
        accountRecords = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(
            Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT ID,Name FROM Account WHERE BillingState = :thePlace.State_Code__c]));
      }
      return accountRecords;
  }
  private set;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35734/discussion-on-answer-by-sebastian-kessel-soql-lookup-on-custom-object-record).

Comment: OK. I asked the question again here with further clarification. Thanks to all who got it this far. I hope I can still reach sebastian.: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110498/is-it-possible-to-pull-up-a-list-of-accounts-that-have-a-billingstate-match-to-a

Comment: please reopen the question.

Comment: error is here List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.